# How can I fix type Error as I am just trying to add an item

Tags: redux, react-redux, dispatch

I am working with redux and I have my actionCreator to add to cart also my reducer function which are below but I keep getting error message which says "actionCreators.js:44 Uncaught TypeError: dispatch is not a function"

**My Reducer**

```
import { ADD_TO_CART } from '../action/types';

const init = [];
const addToCartReducer = (state = init, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      return [...state, ...action.payload];

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default addToCartReducer;
```

**My Action Creator**

```
export const addToCart = (item) => (dispatch) => {
  const product = { ...item, count: 1, sum: item.count * item.prices[0].amount };
  dispatch({
    type: ADD_TO_CART,
    payload: product,
  });
};
```

**Component where I am using it**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Products extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = '';
  }

  render() {
    const {
      products, addProductImage, centered, imageContainer, currency, addToCart, **Passed it as props**
    } = this.props;
    const allProducts = !products ? '' : products.products.map((product) => (
      <article className="card" key={product.id}>
        <div style={imageContainer}>
          <img className="card_image1" src={product.gallery[0]} alt={product.name} />
          {product.inStock ? (
            <img
              src={addProductImage}
              alt={product.name}
              style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
              onClick={addToCart(product)} **Here I call it** 
            />
          )
            : null}
          {!product.inStock ? (<div style={centered}>Out of stock</div>) : null}
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>{product.name}</div>
          <div>{`${currency} ${product.prices[0].amount}`}</div>
        </div>
      </article>
    ));
    return (
      <>{allProducts}</>
    );
  }
}

export default Products;
```

**But I get this error message**

[image: Error message]

I have tried to use it without props, I mean by calling it direct to that component but to no progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the **actionCreator** is a function that returns an action

```
export const addToCart = (product) => ({
    type: ADD_TO_CART,
    payload: product,
});
```

Now to call the action creator in class component you need to use the [connect](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#object-shorthand-form) function from redux

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Products extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = '';
  }

  render() {
    const {
      products, addProductImage, centered, imageContainer, currency, addToCart, **Passed it as props**
    } = this.props;
    const allProducts = !products ? '' : products.products.map((product) => (
      <article className="card" key={product.id}>
        <div style={imageContainer}>
          <img className="card_image1" src={product.gallery[0]} alt={product.name} />
          {product.inStock ? (
            <img
              src={addProductImage}
              alt={product.name}
              style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
              onClick={() => addToCart({ ...product, count: 1, sum: product.count * product.prices[0].amount })}
            />
          )
            : null}
          {!product.inStock ? (<div style={centered}>Out of stock</div>) : null}
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>{product.name}</div>
          <div>{`${currency} ${product.prices[0].amount}`}</div>
        </div>
      </article>
    ));
    return (
      <>{allProducts}</>
    );
  }
}

 const mapDispatchToProps = {
      addToCart,
    }
 export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Products);
```

**Reducer**

```
import { ADD_TO_CART } from '../action/types';

const init = [];
const addToCartReducer = (state = init, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      return [...state, action.payload];

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default addToCartReducer;
```

Comment: Layeb Mazen, thank you for your concern. Do you mean I will write this this.props.addToCart({ ...product, count: 1, sum: product.count * product.prices[0].amount })} Here I call it /> ) : null} {!product.inStock ? (Out of stock) : null} {product.name} {${currency} ${product.prices[0].amount}} )); return ( <>{allProducts}</> ); } }  in the onClick?

Comment: Ah sorry, i updated the code above

Comment: it throws this error "react_devtools_backend.js:4026 Warning: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type."

Comment: change the onclick by this onClick={()=> addToCart({ ...product, count: 1, sum: product.count * product.prices[0].amount })}

Comment: Thank you, Layeb, i am getting a new error entirely and it says action.payload is not iterable.

Comment: Whereas, I am not iterating over anything. I am confused.

Comment: change your reducer to this      ` return [...state, action.payload];`

Comment: @Olamarx i updated the code above

Comment: thank you but the reducer is the same I had.

Comment: I added yours but still the same error.

Comment: Oh, my bad, it just got fixed by indenting your code. but I am yet to see what you changed. Can you point it to me?

Comment: Did you mean that this get resolved by adding my reducer code?

Comment: Yes, it got solved. Thank you very much but I will like to know what you changed.

Comment: The type of the payload is an object and you were destructuring an object in an array ([...state, ...action.payload]). So what I did was just remove the 3 dots ([...state, action.payload])

Comment: Oh, i see that, thank you once again.